# Why iOs code is using so much memory and CPU

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, nsmutablearray, cpu

I have a some permutation/combination code that is iterating through 20 objects taking 5 at a time.  When the list meets some criteria I print the objects that make up that list.  Needless to say the loop is rather large. I place all of the combinations in an NSMutableArray inside of the loop.  Once the objects have been added and pass/fail the test, I remove all of the object from the array.  (Psuedo code below).

```
-(void)CreateCombinations
{
   NSMutableArray *Combinations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   @autoreleasepool {
   NSArray *objectsList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
   @“Lisa”,@“Kevin”,…nil];
   } //autorelease pool

   while(!Finished)
   {
       Combinations = [self getNextCombo: Combinations]
        if (goodCombination)
           [self printCombos:Combinations]

        [Combinations removeAllObject];
   } 
}
```

While monitoring the debug session, CPU and memory are at capacity. I am sure the looping is coming into play. I don't believe that I am reallocating the 'Combinations' Array for every iteration.  If I am, is there something that I can do to make sure that it is properly deallocated or released before the next iteration of the loop?

When I add the @autorelease (which is before the loop) I get a "use of undeclared identifier error".

Comment: How about an autorelease pool?

Comment: Thanks, Mat.  I tried the autorelease pool but it caused some additional problems with adding objects to the array in other sections of the code.

Comment: Here is what I did with the autorelease:
    @autorelease{
     NSArray *objectsList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
       @“Lisa”,@“Kevin”,…nil];
    }

Comment: Well if you show only pseudo code you will get only pseudo suggestions. Show your _real_ code and show what you tried and what problems it caused, and ask about that. Autorelease pool _is_ how you prevent memory from piling up during a loop.

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment, please. Fix your _question_.

Comment: There is no point putting `@autoreleasepool` around the loop. The loop is the problem. You need to put the `@autoreleasepool` _inside_ the loop so that it is called every time thru the loop.

Comment: Also, can you please show more code, real code? There is nothing in the code you have shown that would ever halt the `while` loop, so we would expect to get a (wait for it) stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown is completely fake so it's impossible to guess what your real code is doing wrong. But if you are using memory because you are piling up autoreleased objects during a loop, wrap the interior of the loop in an `@autoreleasepool` block:

```
while (...) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The idea is to release the temporarily used memory every time through the loop.